# Is a landlord required to hire a licensed contractor?

Tags: rental-property, property, landlord, tenant, rent

Is a landlord required to hire a licensed contractor for tenant's repairs? If the landlord is licensed, may the landlord legally perform the repairs?

Let's assume the work being performed is substantial - like replacing all the electrical in the kitchen, or relocating the plumbing for the sink.

For clarification, this is in the USA - if the state matters, then let's say Florida. (Though if the state is important, then I think an answer of 'depends on the state' would be more relevant)

Comment: Can depend on the state and even the county or city. Building codes and landlord rules are generally local.

Comment: IANAL: In my area, I believe the landlord is required to make an honest effort to get the repair fixed to reasonable standard, but how they go about it is up to them. If they make an attempt that fails, they get at least another chance before you have grounds for complaint. The logic is that, "I know a guy" has some value, and even professional contractors make mistakes. I would assume it would be a different story with safety critical things though (Electricity, Heating, etc.)